# Jslint "Line breaking error"

Tags: javascript, jslint

JSLint validation of this snippet

```
1: function foo() {}
2: 
3: foo(1
4: );
5: 
6: foo(
7: );
```

gives this error:

```
Error:

Problem at line 3 character 5: Line breaking error ')'.

foo(1
```

Is this a JSLint bug?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's not a bug. JSLint does more than syntax checking: It enforces certain coding conventions. If you revalidate with the "Tolerate sloppy line breaking" option turned on, you won't get an error.

From the [JSLint Documentation](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html):

> **Line Breaking**
>
> As a further defense against the semicolon insertion mechanism, JSLint  expects long statements to be broken only after one of these punctuation characters or operators:
>
> , . ; : { } ( [ = < > ? ! + - * / % ~ ^ | &
>   == != <= >= += -= *= /= %= ^= |= &= << >> || &&
>   === !== <<= >>= >>> >>>=
>
> JSLint does not expect to see a long statement broken after an identifier, a string, a number, closer, or a suffix operator:
>
> ) ] ++ --
>
> JSLint allows you to turn on the Tolerate sloppy line breaking (laxbreak) option.
>
> Semicolon insertion can mask copy/paste errors. If you always break lines after operators, then JSLint can do better at finding them.